# angular with isotope like sorting?

Tags: javascript, database, sorting, jquery-isotope, querying

I looked for some quesitons to find my answer but ı couldn't succeed. So what I want to do is that let say I want to make a notebook like web app where users can write, attach images and draw some figures on page and I will snap that page as an image with html2canvas (I didn't try it yet but that is not the point for now.) For my porpuse let say those image will be stored somewhere and database will store the relevent data. When user view the thumbnails of pages I want to make them to be used with jquery isotope plugin or some plugin like that with the collaboration of angular js. But it can be used with already loaded js data to sort or filter. Sometimes the ordering or sorting should be done in sql query to not fetch all the rows for the sake of performance. How to manage this. If not clear or complicated entery please warn me. Thanks for reading.